# How to get other field value using jquery.on()

Tags: jquery

I have a simple problem but I can't find how to do this anywhere. I've read the jquery documentation but there's no information about this.

I have one table with generated fields, one row a pair of text and button elements.

```
<input type="text" class="input-text" value="10">
<input type="button" class="input-button">
```

I want to get the value from the text field when I click the button. Since they're generated, so I have to use the .on() function.

```
$('#input-here').on('click', '.input-button', function(event) {
   var value = $('.input-text').val();
   alert(value);
   return false;
});
```

I can get the value but only from the first row of text field. If row #1 is "10", and row #2 is "20", the alert wil only show "10" if I click button in other rows.

Is there any way so that I can get the value correctly?

Comment: Can you add the proper html markup?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/ - Your problem has nothing to do with .on(), it's about tree traversal from a known element (`this`) to another element within a defined html structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the codes, I've tried all the codes but I got 'undefined' from all of those.

The code from @Anto Subash inspired me to get this solution.

```
var value = $(this).parent().find('.input-text').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery's `prev()` method](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to pull the previous element:

```
var value = $(this).prev().val();
```

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the `.prev()` method searches for the predecessor of each of these elements in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

---

> Hi, I just tried this. I got 'undefined'

Your markup provided in the question must be different to the markup you're using on your page. Here's a demo showing this working:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.input-button', function(event) {
   var value = $(this).prev().val();
   alert(value);
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="input-text" value="Foo">
  <input type="button" class="input-button">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="input-text" value="Bar">
  <input type="button" class="input-button">
</div>
```

Comment: @user77177928 I've added a demo snippet to my answer to show that this does work. What is `'#input-here'`?

Comment: Maybe they're in separate table cells. `$(this).closest("tr").find(".input-text")` might do it.

Comment: @James Donnely it's the parent of parent where I generate the row fields. It can work if I don't generate the fields. The fields will be generated later if I click a button.

Comment: @user77177928 then you need to provide all the relevant information in your question. As it stands, myself and several others have answered the question you've asked.

Comment: @James Donnely I already got the answer, thank you for providing your code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prev()` function to get the previous element. Assuming your markup is like in the question.

```
$('#input-here').on('click', '.input-button', function(event) {
   var value = $(this).prev('.input-text').val();
   alert(value);
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#input-here').on('click', '.input-button', function(event) {
   var value = $(this).closest('input').find('.input-text').val();
   alert(value);
   return false;
});
```

Your problem is you have multiple inputs like this

```
<input type="text" class="input-text" value="10">
<input type="button" class="input-button">
```

So if you make a `$('.input-text')` it will get all the input element and `.val()` will get the value of the first element that is why you got the same value every time.

Comment: Hi, I tried your answer and I got 'undefined'.  But I already got the answer, thanks for providing your code :)